# Would iframe in React cause memory leak?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, frontend

Well, this might be a strange question, but there are some differences about the behavior of iframes between a native h5 page and a React page.

- **Native h5 Page**

  Here is a native h5 page with an iFrame. The iframe will create a WebSocket connection.
  We can see the value of `Time` is `Pending` while the connection is still active.

  `![Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDWz3.png)`

  Then after I removed this iframe as a child from document, the value of `Time` became the time the connection lasted.

  `![Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7milk.png)`

> However, in a React Page, something strange happens.

- **React Page**

  Every added iframe would create a WebSocket connection in `Pending` status.

  `![Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgY3K.png)`

  But when I remove them, the value of `Time` wouldn't change into the time they lasted, but still in `Pending` status.

  `![Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCLkY.png)`

  Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [frames, setFrames] = useState([]);

  const onAdd = useCallback(() => {
    const iFrame = (
      <iframe src='http://127.0.0.1:8080/iframe.html' />
    );

    setFrames((frames) => [
      ...frames,
      iFrame,
    ]);
  }, []);

  const onDel = useCallback(() => {
    setFrames((frames) => [
      ...frames.slice(0, frames.length - 1),
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={onAdd}>+1</button>
        <button onClick={onDel}>-1</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {
          frames.map((frame, index) => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                {frame}
              </React.Fragment>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to make some logs in my WebSocket Server, and it seemed that the connections have been disconnected already.

I'm a freshman in frontend development, so this is a strange behavior as for me. I wonder if this caused by **memory leak** or something else.

Sincerely waiting for your answer.